# Memory warnings when trying to load 200+ images

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Update:

Now just using a CollectionView. I should have done this from the start but I was very new to iOS. CollectionViews manage all the getting and releasing of images for you. So no memory trouble at all. Enough tutorials on them on the internet. Just a quick note. Give images a name with a number and don't add zero's before the number. Then you can fetch them with the indexPath.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("AnimationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AnimationCell


        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "bg_\(indexPath.row)")


    return cell
}
```

---

I am building a image viewing app for a graphic novel.  One giant scrollview holding 200+ images.

I tried to build in some memory management based on sample code, but this doesn't seem to work. I guess it doesn't work because I only have memory management on the images and not on the views that hold them.

Is this something where I need to use more "weak" variables and how do I get these to work?

When I put weak in with a variable it tells me it needs a class.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!


    var imageGroup : [UIImage?] = []
    var containerViews : [UIImageView?] = []
    var containerView :UIImageView?
    var imgWidthMult : CGFloat = 2.121875
    let imageGroupCount : CGFloat?
    let containerHeight : CGFloat?
    let containerWidth : CGFloat?
    var imageCounter : Int = 0



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1
        imageGroup = [
            UIImage(named: "bg_001")!,
            UIImage(named: "bg_002")!,
            UIImage(named: "bg_003")!,
            UIImage(named: "bg_004")!,
            //200+ images to follow here
        ]

        let imageGroupCount = CGFloat(imageGroup.count)
        println(imageGroupCount)


        // 3
        for i in 0..<imageGroup.count {
            containerViews.append(nil)
        }

        // 4

        let imagesScrollViewSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imagesScrollViewSize.height * imgWidthMult * CGFloat(imageGroup.count), imagesScrollViewSize.height)

        // 5
        let containerframe = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        let containerHeight : CGFloat = containerframe.height
        let containerWidth : CGFloat = (imgWidthMult * containerHeight)

        loadVisibleImages()

        println("containerWidth")
        println(containerWidth)
        println(containerframe.size)
        println(scrollView.contentSize)




        return
    }

    // this loads images and should be adjusted and taken out of local scope


    func loadImage (imageCounter:Int) {
        let containerframe = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        let containerHeight : CGFloat = containerframe.height
        let containerWidth : CGFloat = (imgWidthMult * containerHeight)

        if imageCounter < 0 || imageCounter >= imageGroup.count {
            // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
            return
        }

        // 1
        if let containerView = containerViews[imageCounter] {
            // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
        } else {
            // 2
            var frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.height * CGFloat(imageCounter) * 2.121875
            frame.origin.y = 0.0
            frame.size = CGSize(width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight)

            // 3
            var newcontainerView = UIImageView(image: imageGroup[imageCounter])
            newcontainerView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            newcontainerView.frame = frame
            scrollView.addSubview(newcontainerView)


            containerViews[imageCounter] = newcontainerView
        }

    }

    func purgeImage(imageCounter:Int) {

        if imageCounter < 0 || imageCounter >= imageGroup.count {
            // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
            return
        }

        // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
        if let containerView = containerViews[imageCounter] {
            containerView.removeFromSuperview()
            containerViews[imageCounter] = nil
            println("removed page")
        }

    }


    func loadVisibleImages() {


        // First, determine which page is currently visible
        let containerframe = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        let containerHeight : CGFloat = containerframe.height
        let containerWidth : CGFloat = (imgWidthMult * containerHeight)
        let pagesWidth = (containerWidth)
        let imageCounter = Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pagesWidth) / (pagesWidth * 2.0)))


        println(Int(floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pagesWidth) / (pagesWidth * 2.0))))
        println(pagesWidth)
        println(containerHeight)


        println(imageCounter)

        // Update the page control

        // Work out which pages you want to load
        let firstPage = imageCounter - 1
        let lastPage = imageCounter + 1


        // Purge anything before the first page
        for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
            purgeImage(index)
        }

        // Load pages in our range
        for var index = firstPage; index <= lastPage; ++index {
            loadImage(index)
        }

        // Purge anything after the last page
        for var index = lastPage+1; index < imageGroup.count; ++index {
            purgeImage(index)
        }
        println("loadVisibleImages")
    }





    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Load the pages that are now on screen
        println("did scroll")
        loadVisibleImages()
        println("did scroll")

    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Edit:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!


    var containerViews : [UIImageView?] = []
    var containerView : UIImageView?
    var imgWidthMult : CGFloat = 2.121875
    let imageGroupCount : Int = 149
    let containerHeight : CGFloat?
    let containerWidth : CGFloat?
    var imageCounter : Int = 000
    var loadingVisibleImages : Bool?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1


        loadingVisibleImages = false

        // 3
        for i in 0..<imageGroupCount {
            containerViews.append(nil)
        }

        // 4

        let imagesScrollViewSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imagesScrollViewSize.height * imgWidthMult * CGFloat(imageGroupCount), imagesScrollViewSize.height)

        // 5

        let containerframe = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        let containerHeight : CGFloat = containerframe.height
        let containerWidth : CGFloat = (imgWidthMult * containerHeight)

        loadVisibleImages()


        return
    }

    // this loads images and should be adjusted and taken out of local scope


    func loadImage (imageCounter:Int) {
        let containerframe = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        let containerHeight : CGFloat = containerframe.height
        let containerWidth : CGFloat = (imgWidthMult * containerHeight)

        if imageCounter < 0 || imageCounter >= imageGroupCount {
            // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
            return
        }

        // 1
        if let containerView = containerViews[imageCounter] {
            // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
        } else {
            // 2
            var frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
            frame.origin.x = ((frame.size.height * CGFloat(imageCounter) * 2.121875) + containerframe.width)
            frame.origin.y = 0.0
            frame.size = CGSize(width: containerWidth, height: containerHeight)

            // 3
            let newImage = UIImage(named: "bg_\(imageCounter + 1)")
            var newcontainerView = UIImageView(image: newImage)
            newcontainerView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            newcontainerView.frame = frame
            scrollView.addSubview(newcontainerView)


            containerViews[imageCounter] = newcontainerView
        }

    }

    func purgeImage(imageCounter:Int) {

        if imageCounter < 0 || imageCounter >= imageGroupCount {
            // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
            return
        }

        // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
        if let containerView = containerViews[imageCounter] {
            containerView.removeFromSuperview()
            containerViews[imageCounter] = nil
            println("removed page")
        }

    }


    func loadVisibleImages() {

        loadingVisibleImages = true

        // First, determine which page is currently visible
        let containerframe = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame;
        let containerHeight : CGFloat = containerframe.height
        let containerWidth : CGFloat = (imgWidthMult * containerHeight)
        let pagesWidth = (containerWidth)
        let imageCounter = Int(floor(((scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pagesWidth) / (pagesWidth * 2.0)))


        println(pagesWidth)
        println(containerHeight)


        println(imageCounter)

        // Update the page control

        // Work out which pages you want to load
        let firstPage = imageCounter - 1
        let lastPage = imageCounter + 1


        // Purge anything before the first page
        for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
            purgeImage(index)
        }

        // Load pages in our range
        for var index = firstPage; index <= lastPage; ++index {
            loadImage(index)
        }

        // Purge anything after the last page
        for var index = lastPage+1; index < imageGroupCount; ++index {
            purgeImage(index)
        }

        loadingVisibleImages = false
        println("loadVisibleImages")
    }





    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Load the pages that are now on screen
        println("did scroll")
        if loadingVisibleImages == false {
        loadVisibleImages()
        }


    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if loadingVisibleImages == false {
            loadVisibleImages()
        }
    }




    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "memory management" doesn't work?  I'm assuming the actual problem is that you're running out of memory, correct?  What exactly do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: You don't seem like managing any memory

Comment: But he calls `super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()`, that counts, right? </sarcasm>

Comment: @nhgrif yes if he implements something in super class, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Actually, on a serious note, I think the memory management he's referring to is probably his `loadImage()` and `purgeImage` methods.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the replies. New to iOS development....
I had a feeling that piece of sample code didn't really do anything (yet)
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please keep in mind that I know nothing ;)

Comment: Could the snark police please wait before closing this question. I have an actual answer for you, OP.

Comment: I was referring to that yes. But also hoping for some super.didReceiveMemoryWarning(magic) 
I think I get memory warnings not because the images aren't "purged" but because I am still loading 200+ objects

Comment: @RMenke Use `tableView`

Comment: Didn't mention this, but the images are all the same size, but wider than the screen (max height). Can I use table cells in the same way I am now using my containers (UIview) ?

Comment: @LyndseyScott There was never a single close vote cast.  There are just a ton of down votes because the question does literally nothing to explain what the actual problem is.  Moreover, just because you can answer a posted question doesn't inherently make that question unsuited for closing.

Comment: @nhgrif I just noticed the strong negative reaction to the question and was worried that people would start trying to close before I got a chance to answer. And it's actually not a bad question at all -- it included code and a clear problem. I think it mainly just had a bad title. But I've edited that.

Comment: I edited the title further, but the question still doesn't actually describe what the actual problem is, and for that, it is bad and deserving of every down vote.  We've edited it and improved it as much as possible, but without completely recreating the entire issue, we can't know what problem is actually being experienced.

Comment: The problem *ISN'T* clear.  He question talks about memory management, which clearly isn't related, but he describes no behavior of his app that would suggest a problem.  Did he look at in instruments and thought it was using to much memory?  Did he run it on a device and it crashed and gave a memory error?  What diagnosis has he done to determine there actually is a problem?

Comment: @nhgrif sorry for the bad title and bad question. New to iOS dev, so I am also new to asking questions about it and formulating them. So any advice is welcome. The problem is simple: It crashes , it says it runs out of memory. I also thought this was clear since loading 200+ images is asking for memory trouble. I also thought that running out of memory had something to do with memory management

Comment: The fact that it crashes and gives you a message about out-of-memory should be included in the description.  I understand being new, but when asking question, you need to describe this behavior exactly, and it's helpful to verbatim copy & paste any error messages you're getting.  If you edit this information into the question (including the verbatim error message), I'll gladly turn my down vote into an upvote.

Comment: Ok! Will crash that app again!

Comment: Crashed it with the same code as the post, but I get no memory error this time. Although it clearly is. I just get this : (lldb) 
On loading the app the memory usage builds up to 95mb (iphone 4s)
This is when loading that array. So clearly I don't need to load the entire array with images on viewdidload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your memory management's the problem. Not Swift's. Here's where you went wrong...

In your `viewDidLoad` method, you've instantiated your `imageGroup` array with 200+ images. Assuming these images aren't super tiny, you've already allocated a *huge* chunk of memory to an unnecessary array from the get go. You should instead fetch these images as needed during your `loadImage` method.

For example, you can replace this line:

```
var newcontainerView = UIImageView(image: imageGroup[imageCounter])
```

with something along the lines of:

```
let newImage = UIImage(named: "bg_\(imageCounter + 1)")
var newcontainerView = UIImageView(image: newImage)
```

so you instead get the image from the bundle on an as-needed basis.

*NB: You'll need to figure out an appropriate filename-getting algorithm to suit your case...`named: "bg_\(imageCounter + 1)"` is just an example.*

As for your use of `imageGroup.count` throughout your code, since it's apparent in your `viewDidLoad` that your images are of a known quantity, I'd suggest replacing all instances of `imageGroup.count` with an equivalent constant.

---

Edit:

To address one other issue with your code, calling `loadVisibleImages` in `scrollViewDidScroll` can also cause memory issues.

The `UIScrollView` delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` is called continuously as the scrollview scrolls, and thus, as your code stands, `loadVisibleImages` will be called nearly constantly as well. So especially when the user's scrolling quickly and your app's simultaneously running multiple iterations of `loadVisibleImages` (where one pass of the method hasn't completed before the next begins), this could result in a crash in this particular case.

So here's a suggestion for now right off the top of my head (I could very well come up with a better one later and I'm sure better ones exist).  In your `scrollViewDidScroll` method, perhaps only call `loadVisibleImages` if your app isn't already going through it. Then call it again as a safeguard once your scrollview has finished decelerating just to make sure you have the visible images.  For example:

```
var loadingVisibleImages

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadingVisibleImages = false
    ...
}

func loadVisibleImages() {
    loadingVisibleImages = true
    ...
    loadingVisibleImages = fasle
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Load the pages that are now on screen
    println("did scroll")
    if loadingVisibleImages == false
        loadVisibleImages()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if loadingVisibleImages == false
        loadVisibleImages()
}
```

Comment: I was thinking it would be something like that!

Comment: Then i also call this later? :
`for i in 0..<imageGroup.count {
            containerViews.append(nil)
        }`

Comment: @RMenke That'd produce either build time errors, compile time errors, or simply do nothing...

Comment: @nhgrif What would "produce either build time errors, compile time errors, or simply do nothing..."

Comment: RMenke's snippet in his comment.

Comment: @RMenke As for all your imageGroup.count lines, can you instead have a constant you declare in your code since you know how many images you have from the get-go? I forgot to put that part in my answer, but will add it.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Thank you for all the help. Is just left the "for i...." were it was. Works fine. 
I also renamed my image assets up to 99. This way i don't need a way to add extra zero's to the name. 

memory varies between 13mb and 150 when scrolling really fast. Then it crashes again. If you don't scroll like a maniac it clears memory perfectly, going back to around 17mb. Is there a way to get the app to clear memory more frequently, or disable scrolling when there is a memory warning?

p.s. people will be reading this at a slow pace.

Comment: @RMenke Glad to hear it's working so far! And you're totally on the right track now with understanding the issue... Congrats! But looking at your code, the way you call `loadVisibleImages` in `scrollViewDidScroll` can be a problem since `scrollViewDidScroll` is called nearly constantly as the scrollview scrolls and thus `loadVisibleImages` will be called nearly constantly as well... So especially when you're scrolling fast, this could be a major issue. I'm running out of space here in my comment, but I'll edit my answer to suggest a fix...

Comment: if only I had the reputation to Vote Up. Thank you for taking the time to follow this up! I also noticed that it calls didscroll all the time, even when you keep a finger to the screen without scrolling. (just anticipating how some people will use it)

Comment: @RMenke No worries about voting up, but I think as the question asker you should be able to "accept" my answer. I think that might help with your rep as well, but I'm not 100% sure about that. Anyway, I've updated my answer with a suggestion. Haven't tested it and it might need some tweaking, but feel free to post here again to let me know how it goes.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Tested it, keeps it in a more acceptable range of memory usage. now it ranges between 17mb and 80mb. Trying to scroll as fast as possible too the end still crashes it. But this is to be expected.

Comment: @RMenke This shouldn't really be expected since you're now only holding on to 3 images at a time. So two things (1) Are any of your images files really big? (2) Other than that, one thing that could be causing an issue for you is that you say you removed this line: `for i in 0..<imageGroup.count { containerViews.append(nil) }` after seeing nhgrif's comment. How are you inserting the containerViews then if you haven't already created the blank indices? I have no idea what your code looks like now, but you may need to add the loop back but use a constant instead of imageGroup.count.

Comment: @LyndseyScott (1)It is true that I am now only loading 3 images at a time. But since all images have the same file size there should be no increase in memory usage. Instead I see the memory usage increases until about 80-100mb and then drops back to 20mb. So i guess he retains some data until space is needed. (2) i left that in since it gave no errors. (after changing it to a constant)

Comment: @RMenke Yeah, you're right about it retaining data until space is needed. You know what... Try adding some autoreleasepools within your `for` loops so the memory's released right away (remove the "@" for Swift): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-SW2 .

Answer (score 2):

Don't load images with [UIImage imageNamed:] for load image in ImageView, it's cause memory issue when no.of images are more,

use this, In Objective-C

```
NSString *imgpath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imgpath];
```

and in Swift 3.0

```
 let imgath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "imageName", ofType: "jpg")
 imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgath!)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reusable scroll view 3rd party framework. It loads and displays images similar way as table view. It uses reusable view on each scroll. You can display small size placeholders and reload actual size of image on focus. Very easy to use:
https://github.com/sumofighter666/ReusableScrollView